# Mysql - Select words from text

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a table contains 300 locations name (Pris, London,...) is there a way (query) to select locations from specified text.

for example:

" Transport for London (TfL) is in talks with its American, Australian and European partners about issuing a single contactless card for Paris, New York".

I want a query to get:

- London
- Paris
- New York

I tried: `SELECT name FROM coutries WHERE name IN ("Transport for London (TfL) is in talks with its American, Australian and European partners about issuing a single contactless card for Paris, New York")`

but no chance!, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT name 
FROM coutries 
WHERE ("Transport for London (TfL) is in talks with its American, Australian and European partners about issuing a single contactless card for Paris, New York") LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%');
```

`IN` does a completely different thing.

Comment: I think he wants the city names from a sentence.

Comment: +1 @Alin, although the "Transport for London..." phrase should be in single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: A string is a sequence of bytes or characters, enclosed within either single quote (“'”) or double quote (“"”). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-syntax.html . Is there a difference? (except ANSI_QUOTES)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve it this way is to use a like %name% in your SQL - You can loop through your names to build the where clause if you need to and I would also suggest adding the stirng to a variable instead of repeating it like I have:

```
SELECT name FROM countries WHERE ('Transport for London (TfL) is in talks with its American, Australian and European partners about issuing a single contactless card for Paris, New York') like '%London%' or ('Transport for London (TfL) is in talks with its American, Australian and European partners about issuing a single contactless card for Paris, New York') like '%Paris%' or ('Transport for London (TfL) is in talks with its American, Australian and European partners about issuing a single contactless card for Paris, New York') like '%New York%';
```

But doing it this way means that you could possibly bring back more results that you are expecting because it doesn't matter where it is in that string; even if is part of another word. You should be Ok if you are passing full country names through but passing something like `united` could being back `United Kingdom` and `United States`.

Answer (score 0):

you can to try to use php to first query for the list of names you have in the database and then compare it with the text.

```
 // connect to the db first..

 // select the names from the db
 $sql = "SELECT names FROM countries";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

 // store names in an array
 $names = array();
 while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $names[] .= $data;
```

then you can use PHP's array functions to extract the names from the text

```
 // store the text in an array per word
 $exploded_text = explode(' ',$text);

 // get the common strings (the names) from both arrays
 $extracted_names = array_intersect($exploded_text,$names);

 print_r($extracted_names);
```

i guess there are better and more efficient solutions to this but i hope you get the idea.

---

`IN` is used as a shortcut for multiple `OR`s, so that the following `WHERE` statement

```
WHERE (name = 'London' OR name = 'Paris' OR name = 'New York')
```

becomes

```
WHERE name IN ('London','Paris','New York')
```